# Flutte: Animate Goolge Map marker like native android?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

i`m trying to animate my google maps marker with continuous LatLng from json API but the probelm is i`m using future to fetch data from my API so this is one time snapshot and the marker is still at the same position i tried Animation function with tween State but this isn`t working still stuck on same poisiton for marker
here is the code for GoogleMaps widget

```
final List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];
```

Animation? _animation;
late GoogleMapController _controller;

final _mapMarkerSC = StreamController<List>();

StreamSink<List> get _mapMarkerSink => _mapMarkerSC.sink;
Stream<List> get mapMarkerStream =>  _mapMarkerSC.stream;

```
final googleMap = StreamBuilder<List<Marker>>(
  stream: mapMarkerStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    return GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lati, longi),
        zoom: 10,
      ),
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
        _controller = controller;
      },
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(snapshot.data ?? []),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    );
  },
);



return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      googleMap,

    ],
  ),
);
```

}

the animation function

```
setUpMarker() async {
  for(int i = 0; i < testList.length; i++){
    _setMarkerIcon() async {
      _carIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          ImageConfiguration(size:  Size(0.5, 0.5)),
          "asset/icons/green1.png"
      );
    }

    var currentLocationCamera = LatLng(testList[i].latitude!.toDouble(), testList[i].longitude!.toDouble());
    final pickUpMarker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(testList[i].regNo!.toString()),
      position: LatLng(currentLocationCamera.latitude, currentLocationCamera.longitude),
      icon: _carIcon,
        /*BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(await getBytesFromAsset('assets/icons/green1.png', 70)),*/
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: testList[i].regNo!.toString(),
      )
    );

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _markers.add(pickUpMarker);
    _mapMarkerSink.add(_markers);
  }
}

animateCar(
    double fromLat,
    double fromLong,
    StreamSink<List<Marker>> mapMarkerSink,
    TickerProvider Provider,
    GoogleMapController controller,
    ) async {
   for(int i = 0; i < testList.length; i++){
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();

      getMarkers() {
        _setMarkerIcon() async {
          _carIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
              ImageConfiguration(size:  Size(0.5, 0.5)),
              "asset/icons/green1.png"
          );
        }
      }

      var carMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("driverMakrer"),
        position: LatLng(testList[i].latitude!.toDouble(), testList[i].longitude!.toDouble()),
        icon:  _carIcon,
```

/*BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(await getBytesFromAsset('assets/icons/green1.png', 60)),*/
anchor: const Offset(0.5,0.5),
rotation: testList[i].heading!.toDouble(),
draggable: false,
);

```
      _markers.add(carMarker);
      mapMarkerSink.add(_markers);

      final animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        vsync: Provider,
      );

      Tween<double> tween  = Tween(begin: 0, end: 1);

      _animation = tween.animate(animationController)
        ..addListener(() async {

          getMarkers() {
            _setMarkerIcon() async {
              _carIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
                  ImageConfiguration(size:  Size(0.5, 0.5)),
                  "asset/icons/green1.png"
              );
            }
          }

          final v  = _animation!.value;
          double lng = v * testList[i].longitude!.toDouble() + (1 - v) * testList[i].longitude!.toDouble();
          double lat = v * testList[i].latitude!.toDouble() + (1 - v) * testList[i].latitude!.toDouble();
          LatLng newPos = LatLng(lat, lng);
          if(_markers.contains(carMarker)) _markers.remove(carMarker);
          carMarker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("driverMarker"),
            position: newPos,/*LatLng(testList[i].latitude!.toDouble(), testList[i].longitude!.toDouble()),*/
            icon: _carIcon,
            /*BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(await getBytesFromAsset('assets/icons/green1.png', 50)),*/
            anchor: const Offset(0.5,0.5),
            flat: true,
            rotation: testList[i].latitude!.toDouble(),
            draggable: false,
          );

          _markers.add(carMarker);
          mapMarkerSink.add(_markers);

          controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                  target: newPos,/*LatLng(testList[i].latitude!.toDouble(), testList[i].longitude!.toDouble()),*/
                  zoom: 15.5
              ))
          );
        });
      animationController.forward();
    });
  }


}


Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
  for(int i = 0; i < testList.length; i++){
    double latI;
    double longI;
    setState(() {
      latI = testList[i].latitude!.toDouble();
      longI = testList[i].longitude!.toDouble();
      animateCar(
        latI,
        longI,
        _mapMarkerSink,
        this,
        _controller,
      );
    });
  }
});
```

and here is the future for fetchData()

```
List<SingleVehicleProvider> testList = [];
```

Future<List>? _future;

Future<List> fetchData() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

```
var secretKey = await prefs.get('secretKey') ??  null;
var customID = customervehiclesID;

var url = "http://api75.trackcaronline.com/api/Vehicle/GetSingleVehicleInfo/$customervehiclesID";
var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'Authorization' : 'bearer $secretKey'
    }
);

var jsonData = json.decode(result.body);

jsonData.forEach((e) async {
  SingleVehicleProvider provider = await SingleVehicleProvider.fromJson(e);
  testList.add(provider);
});
return testList;
```

}

i`m stuck at this probelm for 2 weeks i tried using animarker package and also tried fetching data using Stream but it gave me errors please help me on this

[i`m trying to create my screen like in this GIF URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUUJU.gif)
but my screen is static

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};

  @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            return Scaffold(
    body:
     GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
        compassEnabled: true,
        scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
       
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          usermap = controller;
        

       
        },
      ),
     )
   );
  }
     _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor) 
 {
   MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
    Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
markers[markerId] = marker;
    }
```

that is simple that i used to do all thing this will help you and always call allways call  `setState(() { _addMarker( LatLng(event.latitude, event.longitude), "origin", BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker, );`

}
that is code i use to update marker according to stream

Comment: i couldn`t understand a single word in this

Comment: the thing is i`m not trying to get device location on which my app will be executing i`m trying to get location and LatLng from my API

Comment: instead of using list<markers > only use  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};

Comment: you are adding new marker inside markers list istead use the Map so only that id marker will be updated when you update the value

Comment: okay this part i understand but how can i get stream or continous LatLng from my API?

Comment: Latlng accepts LatLng(latitude,longitutde) now pass that class in function you are getting the latitude and longitude from the api pass that coordinates in the LatLng

Comment: if you did not understands what i am talking about     LatLng position=LatLng(9.222,8.99);  simple answer